# How to correctly create a response for the selected values for Ext.data.TreeStore on django

Tags: python, django, user-interface, extjs, django-models

I have several objects in the database that I want to display in `Ext.tree.Panel` -

```
[
{"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 1, "fields": {"code": "111", "name": "Test Main", "id_parent": 1}},
{"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 2, "fields": {"code": "222", "name": "Test1 ", "id_parent": 1}}, 
{"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 3, "fields": {"code": "333", "name": "Test2 ", "id_parent": 1}}, 
{"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 4, "fields": {"code": "444", "name": "Main Test2 ", "id_parent": 1}}, 
{"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 5, "fields": {"code": "555", "name": "Test3", "id_parent": 4}}, 
{"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 6, "fields": {"code": "666", "name": "Test4", "id_parent": 4}}
]
```

The model itself looks like this:

```
class Storage(models.Model):
    code     =   models.CharField(max_length = 255, null=True)
    name      =   models.CharField(max_length = 255, null=True)
    id_parent  = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How to correctly serialize data for an answer in `Ext.data.TreeStore`?

```
from django.core import serializers
...
    if model == 'Storage':
                if method == 'Read':
                    try:
                        # Read the data                        
                        storage = list(Storage.objects.values('id', 'name', 'id_parent'))
                        result = {'data': storage, 'meta': {'success': True, 'msg': ''}}
                        tree_data = serializers.serialize("json", Storage.objects.all())#How to correctly create an array of data for an answer in Ext.data.TreeStore?
                        print('Look: ' + str(tree_data))                                            
                        return HttpResponse(tree_data)
                        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since here all is stord in a model, we can change the way we query this to:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

# ...

if model == 'Storage' and method == 'Read':
    storage = list(Storage.objects.values('id', 'name', 'id_parent'))
    result = {'data': list_sr, 'meta': {'success': True, 'msg': ''}}
    return JsonResponse(result)
```

By using `.values(..)` we let Django construct such dictionaries itself. We then wrap the result in a Python dictionary (I rewrote `'true'` to `true`, since if we perform a JSON dump, it will otherwise use a string literal, instead of a boolean literal). Finally we return a `JsonResponse`.

In case you want more complex serialization, you should use a [serializer [djando-drf-doc]](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

That being said, I am not confident that a field with `id_parent` is a good idea. Usually in Django, one makes a [**`ForeignKey`** [django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). Django will then automatically generate an `fk_id` field containing the value of the primary key the object refers to.

Comment: With the help of djando-drf-doc or without it, how can I serialize data suitable for Ext.data.TreeStore where "text" and "children" are used

Comment: In that case you better make a `ForeignKey`, and then make a recursive serializer.

Comment: I changed the model by adding ForeignKey and now I'm using the serializer, but I can not correctly serialize the data so that I could use it for Ext.data.TreeStore. How do I do it right? I changed tex in my question.